# Terraform Module for Multiple basic cloud-watch alarms per dynamodb table. Define once use many

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, cloudwatch-alarms

I have 10 dynamo DB tables and I want to have 5 alarms per dynamo DB table, but only want to define those 5 alarms and not repeat them per table in terraform code. on AWS there will still be 50 alarms but I want them not to be repeated in terraform code.

My alarms across all tables will mostly look the same. i.e throughputexceeded exception, Latency Exception, and hence don't want to create separate alarms per table in terraform code. I want that anytime I create a table in terraform these basic alarms gets automatically created without someone needing to add them to terraform

How can I achieve this using terraform?

Comment: Why not have 50 alarms? You can obviously create a combined alarm that monitors the SUM or AVG or MAX of multiple tables, but why would you want that?

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/ - what is your **actual** problem?

Comment: @luk2302 My alarms across all tables will mostly look the same. i.e throughputexceeded exception, Latency Exception, and hence don't want to create separate alarms per table in terraform code. I want that anytime I create a table in terraform these basic alarms gets automatically created without someone needing to add them to terraform.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Please refer above comment

Comment: Create a terraform module for them and reuse them across the board - your question is more about AWS than terraform

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, Not sure how can I do that.. any examples? Also edited question to make more sense.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary. Pretty New to Terraform. Should I have a module called dynamodb and have a cw-alarms.tf file, variables.tf file, main.tf file (responsible for dyanmodb table creation), output.tf file in it .  Let's say I have 5 alarms in cw-alarms.tf file .. so when I create a new table I give this module as the source. Will that create 5 alarms for all table that refer this module ?

Comment: If you can share any code example for any module that creates common alarms per any aws service/resource, that will help.

Comment: Yes, it will create those 5 alarms for that table - check out https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/index.html - try out some code and then open a new question if you really get stuck but terraform docs are easy to read and examples online are plentiful - hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a list somewhere with their names, great, if no you can do something like:

monitoring.tf:

```
locals {

  dynamodb_names = [
    "tableA",
    "tableB",
    "tableC",
    ...
  ]
}
```

And then you can create a single resource that will loop that list.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "foobar" {
  for_each = toset(local.dynamodb_names)
  alarm_name                = "dynamodb-alarm-${each.key}"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = "2"
  metric_name               = "CPUUtilization"
  namespace                 = "AWS/DynamoDB"
  period                    = "60"
  statistic                 = "Average"

  dimensions =  {
     TableName = "${each.key}"
  }
```

It will create all alarms based on the names that are in the `dynamodb_names` list.